# How to run multiple .sh files from different directories

Tags: shell, sh, minecraft, openbsd, bungeecord

**SO** I have a BSD server and want to host a Minecraft BungeeCoord server. The thing is the server files are in different directories
EG: /home/name/bungee/servers/*Survival*/start.sh **AND** /home/name/bungee/servers/*Lobby*/start.sh

Is there a way to make a file that can run multiple files from different directories
?

Just to make it clear, the reason I want to do this is because the BSD server can only take 1 file at a time, like shell/terminal.

Edit: The command I ended up using was `screen`

Comment: "because the BSD server can only take 1 file at a time" -- What do you want to say with that? What is "taking" a file supposed to mean?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant that I need to run multiple .sh files and I don't know how

Comment: And the files are in different directories

Comment: ... by calling each one?

Comment: So when you run a file in the terminal, you can only run one .sh file not multiple

Comment: And I need to run like 6 .sh files in different directories at the SAME time

Comment: You want the process to run in the background? There are a variety of possibilities. Using ` &` at the end of the command, using `nohup`, checking if the program itself can be daemonized by a flag, etc.... Do some research.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228605/discussion-between-yaroslav-o-and-sticky-bit).

Comment: @Yaroslav.O : So your question boils down to run several processes in paralel. I don't see how this is realated to minecraft, but parallel execution is explained pretty well [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-run-command-or-code-in-parallel-in-bash-shell-under-linux-or-unix/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*somewhat sorted by least to most advanced*

#### example 1

```sh
sh /home/name/bungee/servers/Survival/start.sh &
sh /home/name/bungee/servers/Lobby/start.sh &
```

`&` runs the process as a background job freeing the terminal (`STDIN`) though not `STDOUT` and `STDERR` streams meaning the output still goes to the terminal

use [jobs(1)](https://man.openbsd.org/ksh#jobs) command of `ksh(1)` (OpenBSD default shell) to view those jobs controllable by your shell afterwards

#### example 2

after `cd` path gets shorter

```sh
  cd /home/name/bungee/servers
  sh ./Survival/start.sh &
  sh ./Lobby/start.sh &
```

you may also redirect both output to file instead of to the screen using the redirection capability of your shell such as with `> output.log 2>&1`

#### example 3

use multiple (virtual) terminals? (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>) logging in into each separately, and then launch a script per [tty(4)](https://man.openbsd.org/tty.4)

#### example 4

use a programming language library such as [IPC::Cmd](https://perldoc.perl.org/IPC::Cmd) to fork processes with [run_forked](https://perldoc.perl.org/IPC::Cmd#$hashref-=-run_forked(-COMMAND,-%7B-child_stdin-=%3E-SCALAR,-timeout-=%3E-DIGIT,-stdout_handler-=%3E-CODEREF,-stderr_handler-=%3E-CODEREF%7D-);) function

Comment: `for` loop (with `find(1)`) and wildcard (`*`) are also options for multiple files TMTOWTDI